# Can you add a virtual disk to a VM but present it as an external disk

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

I need to temporarily add a disk to a VM (esxi 6.5 - windows or linux), but I don't want it to appear as physically attached (internal) storage, I want it to appear as though I've plugged an external usb hard disk in.

NOTE: I don't want to plug an *actual* external drive in, I just want to add a *virtual* disk that appears like an external drive

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

No, why are you trying to do this anyway?

Comment: Can i just offline a disk (in diskmgmt) and remove it from the VM without a reboot etc?

Comment: Entirely depends on the guest OS, but generally yes

Comment: I basically just want to add a 500GB disk to a server for a day or two to perform some operations on some data, and then remove it - all without rebooting. Windows Server 2016, but I'd be interested in a CentOS 7 scenario too

Comment: 2016 will be fine, as will RHEL7+